# How to set foreign key using value from nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I have a Rails app that displays `Content`. Each piece of Content belong_to a `Source` and a Source has_many Contents. Each Source consists of a `name` and a `domain`.

The Content also belongs_to an `Edition`. The way my app is set up is, in the form to create/edit `Editions`, I have nested the form fields for `Contents`, using the Cocoon gem.

The nested fields for contents include a `link` field. What I need to do is check the `link` against the various `domains` in the Sources table and set the relevant `source_id` on the newly created/edited content.

I was thinking that I could set the relevant `source_id` in the `editions controller` on the `update` or `create` actions. However, since the only data I receive is a params hash with an embedded `contents_attributes` hash (which holds no reference to the `source_id`, since the `source` is not set in the form), how can I set the `source_id` using the 'link' submitted on the form?

Here's my create and update actions on the editions_controller:

```
def create
  @edition = Edition.new(edition_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @edition.save
      format.html { redirect_to @edition, notice: 'Edition was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @edition }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @edition.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @edition.update(edition_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @edition, notice: 'Edition was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @edition }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @edition.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And here are the params used:

```
def edition_params
  params.require(:edition).permit(:date, 
                                  :clicks, 
                                  :product_id,
                                  contents_attributes: [:id,
                                                        :heading,
                                                        :body,
                                                        :link,
                                                        :top_story,
                                                        :section_id,
                                                        :_destroy
                                                       ]
                                 )
end
```

Should I have a hidden input on the form with the source_id? Or can this be done as is on the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the `link` value set in contents form AND you have a logic to determine the `source` from the value of `link`, then you don't need to set `source_id` in form OR in the controller.

Best place to set the `source_id` would be in the model, so that it is always set no matter how you create the `content` record i.e. from editions form, from console, or from some other controller. You won't have to worry about that in this case.

Having these associations and callbacks in your models should solve your purpose:

```
class Source
  # field :name
  # field :domain

  has_many :contents

  def self.fetch_from_link(link)
    match_link_with_domains_and_return_source_record
  end
end

class Edition
  # field :date
  # field :clicks

  has_many :contents
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contents
end

class Content
  # field :heading
  # field :body
  # field :link
  # field :top_story

  belongs_to :source
  belongs_to :edition

  before_validation :set_source

  private

  def set_source
    # Set source *only* if not already set. You can change `||=` to `=` to set it always.
    self.source ||= link && Source.fetch_from_link(link)
  end
end
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! :D I ended up replacing the `||=` with just `=`, as you stated, since I wanted it to work whenever the link was edited as well. One thing I didn't understand though was why did you use the `&&` in the last line: `self.source ||= link && Source.fetch_from_link(link)`? On that note, why not just say `self.source = Source.fetch_from_link(link)`

Comment: It is same as `Source.fetch_from_link(link) if link`, only more pretty. You don't want to run into error when link is `nil`.

Comment: Oh OK, is it because saying `link && Source.fetch_from_link(link)` checks that both items exist, but only returns the last item, i.e. `Source.fetch_from_link(link)`?